# get image from folder with imageurl in database and show that in my browser with echo in golang

Tags: go, echo, imageurl

I  get  my data from database and they show in browser or software like postman the same as this

```
/ 20221125143847
// http://localhost:3000/api/v1/datesmain/read

{

"alldates": [
{
  "ID": 1,
  "CreatedAt": "2022-11-25T00:00:00Z",
  "UpdatedAt": "2022-11-25T00:00:00Z",
  "DeletedAt": null,
  "volume": "20",
  "image_url": "/assets/images/IMG_3429.jpg\n",
  "average_weight": 7.5,
  "dates_type_id": 1,
  "wight_type_id": 1
},
{
  "ID": 2,
  "CreatedAt": "2022-11-25T00:00:00Z",
  "UpdatedAt": "2022-11-25T00:00:00Z",
  "DeletedAt": null,
  "volume": "15",
  "image_url": "/assets/images/IMG_3436.jpg\n",
  "average_weight": 7.5,
  "dates_type_id": 1,
  "wight_type_id": 1
}
  ]
}
```

as you se image url is currect and all images are in filder in root of project with the name of "assets"
as I undrestand its possible show my image by this URL

> http://localhost:3000/api/v1/datesmain/assets/images/IMG_3429.jpg

I want to show all of them as a listview in front end with java or ...

but when copy and past one of url in browser like this

> // http://localhost:3000/api/v1/datesmain/static/images/IMG_3429.jpg
> {
> "message": "Not Found"
> }

How can I resolve that?

and this is my tiny code

```
func ReadAllDatesMain(e echo.Context) error {
ad, err := logic.ReadAllDatesMain()
if err != nil {
    return nil
}
return e.JSON(http.StatusOK, map[string]interface{}{
    "alldates": ad,
})
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined route for your API but not for your files. You need to set [static route](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/static-files/) in echo. Then you can access the folder structure by URL from client like browser or postman.

Comment: I added  e := echo.New()
 e.Static("/assets", "assets")